# scheduled.task.cronExpression is unknow property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, expression

scheduled.task.cronExpression=0 0 12 * * ?  # Default cron expression at noon

I am trying to scheduled.task.cronExpression in spring boot application.properties but I am getting Warning
that scheduled.task.cronExpression is unknown property
Why?

I was expecting that I will not get warning

Comment: Because, as the warning states, that isn't a property. At least not a default property.